# MySQL temporarily modify database for development

Tags: php, mysql, windows-10

For development I have a set of tables in a database I want to modify the tables during development and testing. But be able to go back to the original state i started with every time I run the application. is there a way to achieve this without actually backing up and restoring every time.
OS: Win10 Software: XAMPP MySQL(MariaDB) with PHP

Comment: The obvious solution is not using that database for development; copy it and use the copy. Although you should probably not test with live data at all...

Comment: Like Jeroen said, use a copy. Don't ever use your production database for testing/developing.

Comment: Thanks, The data is just sample data. but during testing i exhaust most of the data (modified/deleted) every time. If using a copy is the right way to do it can you illustrate how to do it using MySQL or XAMPP

Comment: just make a backup and then restore the backup with a different name. Then point the dev/test environment of your application (you do have a different "test" copy of your application as well, I hope?) at the new copy of the database. Each time you want to "go back to the start", just restore the backup again. Backup/restore is scriptable, so you can automate it if you need to.

Comment: @ADyson Please answer in the answer section

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I considered it more of a suggestion than an answer, tbh

Comment: @ADyson Well we can't peer review it which is a problem. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question, ta :) FWIW I think your answer is correct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit fair point, I guess. I've added it to the answers.

Comment: @ADyson Nice one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a backup and then restore the backup with a different name. Then point the dev/test environment of your application (you do have a different "test" copy of your application as well, I hope?) at the new copy of the database.

Each time you want to "go back to the start", just restore the backup (with the alternative name) again.

Backup/restore is scriptable, so you can automate it if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is being exhausted as you say there's no other way than return to original state, but you might look for the ways to make it faster and easier. If the db is big and you look to shorten the restore time look at the suggestions here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster

Also you can write a shell script that wraps the restore operations suggested in one of the solutions from the link above in single command.